# How to unit test T-SQL code using Resharper test runner?

Tags: t-sql, unit-testing, resharper

Basically, the title says it all: I am using the Resharper test runner (my tests are written using NUnit), and now I need to test some T-SQL code.

How do I do that?

Any help (links to tutorials & co.) would be appreciated.

What I do not know is:

- Where do I put the tests? C#? T-SQL as well? ...?
- How do I setup the test runner to run these tests?
- Is this even possible with Resharper?

Comment: When you say "T-SQL", do you mean select statements, stored procedures or UDFs? Or all of them?

Comment: All of them, mainly classical CRUD statements, but also stored procedures.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking here. What prevents you from writing your tests in C# using NUnit and ADO.NET that makes use of those statements? On the other hand, why not use [tSQLt](http://tsqlt.org/)?

Comment: If I do it using C# and NUnit, it's not a unit test any more, but an integration test (I test C# code to access the DB and the stored procedure). tSQLt looks nice, but is an extra tool. I hoped that you could get it included in what is already there.

Comment: I disagree that it is an integration test. You don't test the production code that access the database. Instead you are using ADO.NET directly inside your NUnit test just as a technical means to be able to test the statements. You don't test the integration of your app with the database. Having said that, I suggest you don't go this route. Use a database unit testing framework like tSQLt for unit testing database code.

Comment: Integrating tSQLt into Resharper should theoretically be possible using the ReSharper plugin mechanism and APIs but according to my research such a plugin doesn't exist yet. And it would be a bit of an abuse of the unit testing infrastructure in Resharper, because it works Visual Studio projects.

Answer (score -1):

I have written some unit tests for T-SQL that tests for syntactical errors in the Sql code. There tests are executed from C# in NUnit or Microsofts Unit testing Framework and run with the preceding statement:

```
SET FMTONLY ON;
```

[Microsoft reference of this statement.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx)

After you only get back metadata so nothing is really executed after this, so you can even test queries that would usually modify data.

For example, see this NUnit-test below that will be succesful if the Procedure exists and has no syntactical error in it self or in any of the stored procedures dependencies.

```
[Test]
public void GivenStoredProcedure_WhenParsedBySqlServer_ThenItsResultShouldBeZero()
{
    const string sqlText = "SET FMTONLY ON; EXEC dbo.MyStoreProc;";

    var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlText, sqlConnection);
    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    try
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        var result = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();              
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(0));
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        sqlConnection.Dispose();
    }      
}
```